# How to load data into ViewController from local JSON file

Tags: ios, json, local

I'm developing an iPhone app and I need to show stored data in a TableView.
After some research I decided that JSON would be best fit for storing the data. However, I couldn't find any tutorials explaining how to read JSON as a local file rather than
from a remote source, as often is the case.

Any tutorials you could recommend?

Comment: When you say _local file_, are you saying the JSON file is stored in the Documents directory or embedded as a resource in the app bundle?

Comment: By the way, while JSON is a fine format (esp for exchanging data with a server), if this is a local resource only, a [property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048-CJBGDEGD) (aka a "plist" file) might be simpler. You create a property list file with `[dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];`. You read a plist with `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];`. This is less cumbersome than using JSON.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) for this.

```
NSError *deserializingError;
NSURL *localFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathStringToLocalFile];
NSData *contentOfLocalFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localFileURL];
id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile 
                                            options:opts 
                                              error:&deserializingError];
```

Comment: `NSURL` does not have a method named `urlWithString`. If you wish to create an `NSURL` from a file path, you need to use `NSURL fileURLWithPath:`.

Comment: Sorry, capitalization was wrong, it should have been `URLWithString`. But you're right `fileURLWithPath:` is the way to go for file paths

Comment: I used:     `NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"employees"                                                      ofType:@"json"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                error:&error];`

Answer (score 23):

First of all: you need to load your local json string. Assuming the jsonstring is inside your project, to load it, first create nsstring pointing to the file:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"THENAMEOFTHEFILE" ofType:@"EXTENSIONOFYOUTFILE"];
```

second, load the data of file:

```
NSData *content = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

third, parse the data:

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:content options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```